# Ruby Help with Dynamic Methods

Tags: ruby

I need some help with defining a dynamic method.

Basically, I have many classes that reside within one module. I need to generate a list of methods within each class based on a passed in list of strings, which is specific to each class (i.e. different classes have different list of strings). The body of the method should be something like:

```
client.call(the_string, @an_instance_variable)
```

So basically I want to create a method that I can use in each of these classes that reside within the same module, in order to dynamically generate a bunch of methods based on the array of strings that was passed.

Something like:

```
register_methods @@string_array
```

So say "name" was a string in the array, then it would generate a method as such:

```
def name
  client.call("name", @an_instance_variable)
end
```

I hope that makes sense. I'm stumped after trying all sorts of things for hours, and would really appreciate any input. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't have an irb available, but this should work

```
def register_methods strings
  strings.each do |s|
    define_method s.to_sym do
      client.call("name", @an_instance_variable)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you intend do use the @an_instance_variable, but you can also define methods that takes arguments like this:

```
def register_methods *methods
  methods.each do |method|
    define_method method do |arg|
      client.call(method, arg)
    end
  end
end
```

So if you send register_methods("name", "age") you would have two new methods looking like this:

```
def name(arg)
  client.call("name", arg)
end

def age(arg)
  client.call("age", arg)
end
```